# Cucumber tags chaining

Tags: testing, cucumber, e2e-testing, gherkin

I was thinking about chaining tags

base example from https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/

```
@billing
Feature: Verify billing

  @important
  Scenario: Missing product description
    Given hello

  Scenario: Several products
    Given hello
```

what I would like to do is

```
@billing
Feature: Verify billing

  @important
  Scenario: Missing product description
    Given hello

  Scenario: Several products
    Given hello please run @important tag
```

and all the steps from @important would execute, is that possible? I didn't find any examples in google :(
if yes could you help me find some materials?

Stack:
JS with **cypress-cucumber-preprocessor** https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor
I also looked over all the examples and didn't see anything like that

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're saying that you'd like to be able to re-use the steps from an existing scenario in another one, is that correct?

Instead of trying to organise the re-use at the Gherkin level (which is not a programming language, but a *specification language*) I would do it a level down in the code in your step definitions.

A really nice pattern to help you organise your step def code is the screenplay pattern, which would allow you to create composable "chunks" of automation code that you can re-use.

Here's a blog post I wrote about that pattern: https://cucumber.io/blog/bdd/understanding-screenplay-(part-1)/